# Import OSX bundles in golang?

Tags: macos, go

So, in python if I want to access an OSX bundle I can use the objc module like this:

```
import objc
objc.loadBundle('CoreWLAN', 
       bundle_path='/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework', 
       module_globals=globals())
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in golang, perhaps with a module? Google is not finding me much. Do I have to call out to this using the C import features of the language? Is this even possible?

My specific situation is that I would like to read WIFI data for available access points, channels, signal strength and signal/noise ratio for talking to the Google Maps Geolocation API.

Comment: If possible at all, than through C.

Comment: A .framework bundle contains at its top level a dynamically loaded library. In the case of the system frameworks, this dynamically loaded library's filename is the base name of the framework, and does not have the typical `.dylib` extension. If you are willing to use [libdl directly](https://github.com/andlabs/dl), which means cgo, you can dynamically load this dylib and call its functions directly. But since we're using cgo at this point, there's a better way: `//cgo LDFLAGS: -framework CoreWLAN` and then use the API directly from cgo.

Comment: And in fact, looking into it, CoreWLAN's API is Objective-C based, so you have no choice but to use cgo and do the latter of what I said :/ (Do not try to use the Objective-C runtime API directly; that leads to verbose, unsafe, and nonportable code.)

Comment: I figured I'd need cgo, you should put this as an answer as it's what I'm definitely going to do. Thanks mang!

Answer (score 2):

Andlabs gave an excellent response that he has unfortunately not put in as an answer.

Basically you use cgo like this...

```
//cgo LDFLAGS: -framework CoreWLAN
```

...and you are able to call into the framework directly. To quote his responses:

> A .framework bundle contains at its top level a dynamically loaded library. In the case of the system frameworks, this dynamically loaded library's filename is the base name of the framework, and does not have the typical .dylib extension. If you are willing to use libdl directly, which means cgo, you can dynamically load this dylib and call its functions directly. But since we're using cgo at this point, there's a better way: //cgo LDFLAGS: -framework CoreWLAN and then use the API directly from cgo. –  andlabs
>
> And in fact, looking into it, CoreWLAN's API is Objective-C based, so you have no choice but to use cgo and do the latter of what I said :/ (Do not try to use the Objective-C runtime API directly; that leads to verbose, unsafe, and nonportable code.) –  andlabs